# Sphinx searchd connection refused by local host

Tags: ubuntu, sphinxsearch

I have sphinx setup to run in config files on port 3312.  I can use the indexer, and create the index.  I can search.

I can't run searchd to return queries. I tried telnet 127.0.0.1 3312.  My connection is refused.

Whats my next step?  I am not very good with Iptables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start searchd first, something like `/usr/local/bin/searchd` (you should use actual path to searchd, try `locate searchd` to get it)

Okay, it looks like you have two `listen` directives in your config:

```
listen = {port}
listen = {sql_host}:{sql_port}:mysql41
```

and the second one is obviously not right

Comment: I have tried.  My result is this:

using config file '/usr/local/etc/sphinx.conf'...
WARNING: compat_sphinxql_magics=1 is deprecated; please update your application and config
listening on all interfaces, port=3306
bind() failed on 0.0.0.0, retrying...
bind() failed on 0.0.0.0, retrying...

Comment: Please double check your configuration file, it tries to bind to port 3306 which is not right, 3306 is a MySQL port.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to specify the config file. This is my result:

listening on all interfaces, port=3312
listening on 127.0.0.1:3306
bind() failed on 127.0.0.1, retrying...
bind() failed on 127.0.0.1, retrying...
bind() failed on 127.0.0.1, retrying...
bind() failed on 127.0.0.1, retrying...
bind() failed on 127.0.0.1, retrying...

Comment: You should set `listen = 3312` in the `searchd` section of your Sphinx config file.

Comment: Yes it was previously set as that. but as you can see from the previous post something else is causing issues.

Comment: Could you please post your full config somewhere (say, to pastebin.com) and post a link here?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/JwLb9Qze  --> sphinx.conf

Comment: http://pastebin.com/YqffTYbX  --> import file

Comment: I am however missing the .pid file.  Am I supposed to create that, or is it created when the service is ran.

Comment: I edited my answer, I think the problem is that you generate the config with two `listen` lines, you should just delete or comment out the second one.

Comment: Yes, I commented that second directive out.  Although it is still having issues with the .pid.  I manually created the .pid file with proper permission, but it doesnt seem to like it very much.  Thank you for your help

Comment: Well, your pid path is set to `pid_file = {root}/searchd.pid` and `root` resolves to `''` according to your config, you should use `/var/run/searchd.pid`, `/searchd.pid` is not writable I guess.

Comment: Actually its only an issue when I try to stop the service.  Removing the directive you pointed out now fixes the search.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because the port is already hold by some else daemon. If the '127.0.0.1:3306' is failed - it is nothing surprising, since 3306 is the port for mysqld.
You can try the 9312 (sphinx api) and 9306 (sphinxql) as official IANA assigned ports for sphinx.